# text_generator.py "Access is Denied"

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm having trouble with this code. For some reason whenever I use the test client, I get this message.

```
import stdio
import sys
from markov_model import MarkovModel


def main():
    k = int(sys.argv[1])
    T = int(sys.argv[2])
    # text from standard input initialized to variable
    text = sys.stdin.read()
    # slices text and initializes it to kgram
    kgram = text[:k]
    model = markov_model(text, k)
    # model is used to generate random length of text
    stdio.writeln(model.gen(kgram, T))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

text_generator.py 5 50 < data / bible.txt
Access is denied.

Comment: How are you trying to run it? Can you provide the full traceback in your question?

Comment: The error is probably occurring at the shell level. It cant open one of the files mentioned in the command. Do you have permission to read `bible.txt` also should there be spaces in the path?

Comment: The file bible.txt is in a file named data. I'm new to python, so I'm not sure how to get "permission", when I can open the file just fine in Notepad, but not in PyCharm.

Comment: Did you make the Python script executable? If not, you should run it as `python text_generator.py 5 50 < data/bible.txt` or make it executable using `chmod`.

Comment: I tried this and for some reason there isn't any output at all.

Comment: Put extra print statements in your code and see if they are executed.